# JSON parsing data iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I parse this data to use it: I am getting below data using NSString and showing it on console through NSLog.

```
HTML = {"session":"2a1d9a1db71b443d7a9702816663d8d","role":"normal","account":"uid\u003ddemo@url.com,o\u003dDemo,o\u003dUnd"}
```

I want to get the values of accounts and then want to use them to select one of them for which I will use picker view.

and this data array:

```
Group = ["DEMO"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take this html response in NSDictionary and then access it elements by using the following code

> NSDictionary *html = [responseString JSONValue];
> NSString * session = [html objectForKey:@"session"]//returns session id
> NSString * role = [html objectForKey:@"role"]
> NSString *accounts = [html objectForKey:@"account"]//This will get the accounts string with comma separated.
> NSArray *accountList = [account componentsSeparatedByString:@","];//It will return the array of all acount values which you can use in picker view to select one

you can check this by checking the array size such that

> if(accountList.count>1)
> {
> //contains multiple accounts
> }
> else (if(accountList.count == 1)
> {
> //only one account
> } 
> else 
> {
>  //No account
> }

Comment: thanx @Manish for help.. I have one more question here that how can i count that if user has one account or multiple accounts, because if he has one account then he will be shown another main view while if he has more than 1 account then he will be shown accounts picker view

Comment: I have edited my answer , now you can find out the numbers of accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) to parse the JSON data.

Include downloaded JSONKit files to your project. Import that .h file.

```
//HTML is your downloaded string JSON Feed
NSDictionary *deserializedData = [HTML objectFromJSONString];

//Helpful snippet to log all the deserialized objects and their keys
NSLog(@"%@", [deserializedData description]);
```

Comment: I am using SBJson, I want to know how can I extract the accounts data from this object and then use them, as in this data it  is showing 3 accounts so user will be shown a new view to select relevant account and if there is single account in the data user will be shown another view.